# Unable to call new object Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

`enter code here`I created a new javascript file/object(File 2) and I'm trying to create the new object in file 1, however; i get an "object is not defined error". I have the reference  present in the aspx file.

JS File 1

```
dosomething function()

{

    var RedNotesDisplay = new RedNotesDisplayController(redNotesArray, "22", draggedRowsContainer);
}
```

Js File 2

```
function RedNotesDisplayController(redNotesContent, JQueryPositionInformation, containerId)
{
    var _redNotesContent = redNotesContent;
    var _JQueryPositionFormation = JQueryPositionInformation;
    var _containerId = containerId;
    var _redNotesDiv = "";
}
```

Here's the error

```
var RedNotesDisplay = new RedNotesDisplayController(redNotesArray, "22", draggedRowsContainer);  <- 'RedNotesDisplayController' is undefined
```

Comment: There's not really enough information to go on here. Could you try to clarify? What line is the error on, etc.

Comment: `dosomething function()` is not valid javascript.  Did you mean `function dosomething()` ?

Comment: What line is it saying the error is on? and where are redNotesArray, draggedRowsContainer defined

Comment: var RedNotesDisplay = new RedNotesDisplayController(redNotesArray, "22", draggedRowsContainer); is where the error lies

Comment: The error means that `RedNotesDisplayController` doesn't exist where you are trying to access it. Since we don't know anything about how these two files are loaded there is nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: are you including the js files in the file where the line with the error is thrown?

Comment: @mjw yes. I am referencing both files in the Aspx file I'm using.

Comment: try coding var ns = { RedNotesDisplayController: function(){ // do work} };

Answer (score 0):

Try this. What is going on here is we are creating a namespace called ns. Here is another article that helps articulate this concept and how it can be applied.
[How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript)

```
   var ns = {
    RedNotesDisplayController: function (redNotesContent, JQueryPositionInformation, containerId)
    {
        var _redNotesContent = redNotesContent;
        var _JQueryPositionFormation = JQueryPositionInformation;
        var _containerId = containerId;
        var _redNotesDiv = "";
        return "i am return string";
    }
};
var RedNotesDisplay = ns.RedNotesDisplayController([1,2,3], "22", "<div></div>");

// i use console.log to display the string in developer tools [Console]
console.log(RedNotesDisplay);
```

since ns could be  undefined in another page, you are losing scope. Try this code to verify what your constructor is for this js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var somethingNew = new ns.RedNotesDisplayController([1, 2, 3], "22", "<div></div>");
        alert(somethingNew.constructor);
    </script>
```

You should now get a response from localhost (my response for example) : **function (n,t,i){var r=n,u=t,f=i;return"i am return string"}**

Comment: 'ns' is undefined.

Comment: since ns is undefined, you are losing scope. Try this code to verify what your constructor is for this js.